# UWP: Listview when loaded for first time shows a grey background for less than a second and then disappears before the actual content

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Whenever the listview is loaded for the first time, it displays a flash of grey background for less than half a second and then disappears before the actual content is loaded. My code is as follows (pretty straight forward) Any thoughts?

```
<ListView Name="FilterCategories" SelectionMode="None"
                                  FlowDirection="LeftToRight" >
                            <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                <TransitionCollection/>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="filter:FilterCategory">                            
                                    <Grid Name="FilterHeaders">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Name="Header" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                       Margin="20,10,0,0" Text="{x:Bind NameAlias}" 
                                                       Opacity="{x:Bind Opacity}"
                                                       Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <RelativePanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,15,0">
                                            <TextBlock Name="DownArrow" Text="&#xE70D;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="8" 
                                                             Visibility="{x:Bind IsCollapsed}" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Left"
                                                             FontWeight="Bold"
                                                             Tapped="DownArrow_Tapped" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Margin="0,10,10,0">
                                            </TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Name="UpArrow" Text="&#xE70E;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="8" 
                                                               Visibility="{x:Bind IsExpand}" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                                                               TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Tapped="UpArrow_Tapped" Margin="0,10,10,0">
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </RelativePanel>                                
                                        <Grid  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UpArrow,Path=Visibility}"
                                               Margin="10,10,0,0">
                                            <ListView SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{x:Bind FilterCategoryItems}"
                                                                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
                                                <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                                    <TransitionCollection/>
                                                </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>                                                
                                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="filter:FilterCategoryItem">
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <CheckBox x:Name="FilterCheckBoxTask" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStylePlainView}" 
                                                                                                  IsThreeState="False" Opacity="0.2"
                                                                                                  MinWidth="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind NameAlias}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ListView>                                     
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Height="10" 
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                BorderBrush="#f0f0f0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>                         
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

**The item source is being set dynamically in the code behind**

Comment: Can you provide a gif of the issue ? From what i can understand it is due to listview virtualization -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization

Comment: I've attached a gif of the issue above. And this is not frequently reproducible. But it occurs intermittently

Comment: @Karthik I agree with Pratyay, it looks like placeholder is placed on your listview when your CPU cannot render properly for all your items. Do you have a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? How you set your ItemsPanel?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT I've updated the code above. That's the exact code I'm using... I didn't explicity set the ItemsPanelTemplate as of now.. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Karthik Actually the keypoint is also related to your datasource. If you haven't set it then you are using the default one, then it's OK for itemspanel.  What about also provide us a demo itemsource which can reproduce your issue. Note, for security reason you'd better delete any sensetive data and just show us demo data.